# Scrolling to top of hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to scroll a div to the top while it is hidden. Here's my sample code:

```
 function slideUpReset(div) {
    $(div).slideUp('fast', function() {
        $(div).scrollTop(0);
    });
}
```

But this doesn't work. `$(div).scrollTop(0)` only works when the div isn't hidden. Is there a way I can achieve the effect I want?

Comment: I assume you re-show the div later on, can't you set the scroll position just after it's shown again?

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/subhash9/bLcnx/12/):

```
if($('#div').prop('display')=='none')
{
$('#div').scroll();
    $("#div").animate({ scrollTop: 1000 }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't just link to a fiddle. (But I didn't the downvote)

Comment: plus the OP issue is not even addressed

Comment: rules says that you need to post also code, not just link to jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is wrap the hidden div in another div then scroll to that
eg:

```
<div id=wrapperdiv> ** your hidden div ** </div>
```

then update your jquery to scroll to this div

```
 function slideUpReset(div) {
    $(div).slideUp('fast', function() {
        $(div).parent().scrollTop(0);
    });
 }
```

Comment: OP is not trying to scroll TO a div, he's trying to set the scroll position OF the div